# “help somebody do something” vs “help do something”

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between saying “she helped her bake” and “she helped bake”?

I tend to overthink sentences so bear with me if I sound stupid, but to me the latter sounds like she helped *by baking* as in she did the action by herself and that was helpful, but I don’t know if that’s how it really works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not quite it.

As far as I can see, the only difference between the two sentences is that the first one makes known the agent receiving help (**her**). Otherwise, they both mean the same thing and **she** offered help in both cases— either by involving herself directly in the process of baking (a cake, perhaps) or by giving instructions, perhaps.

A fuller version of the first sentence might read thus:

> She helped her (to) bake [a cake].

You could use the infinitive marker *to* or simply discard it, in which case it's called a *bare infinitive.*

> She helped (to) bake.

Normally, you would use this sentence when some earlier context is already known: the agent receiving help is already known and so is the item baked. Then you could casually remark *She helped bake.*